# Facebook: can't post image to feed

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've an iOS app that needs to post images to people's walls.

What I do is upload the image to the user's album, get the link of that image and post it to the user's wall like so:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       kAppId, @"app_id",
                                       imageLink, @"link", 
                                       thumbURL, @"picture",
                                       toUserId, @"to",
                                       nil];

        [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

And I get the following error: "`FBCDN image is not allowed in stream...`"

remarkably it doesn't happen when I'm logged with my developer username but with other usernames (Every username that I tested besides the DEV username that "administers" the FB App).

Comment: Please use graph API for that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152413/posting-picture-on-facebook-feed-from-an-iphone-app-using-graph-api

Comment: review the link. it will work for you.

Comment: Why do you think so? Why should I use ASIHTTPRequest? What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: you said you use graph API then why you use this  [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self] line it is for facebook dialog not for graph API you can user FBRequest in place of ASIHTTPRequest

Comment: I tried: [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                             andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self]; and nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `object_attachment` parameter; see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: As for me "object_attachment" doesn't work properly. See the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/23199781/989896 to review my solution

Answer (score 0):

Here try to use my function .. its work with me

```
- (void) uploadImageWithName : (NSString*)name
{

    UIImage *uploadImage = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"some text",  
                               @"message",
                               [fb accessToken], 
                               @"access_token",nil];

    [params setObject:uploadImage forKey:@"source"];

    [fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                         andParams: params
                     andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];

}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "publish_stream" permissions to upload a photo.